# Jekyll - can you use liquid to reference front matter variables

Tags: jekyll

I would like to use front matter variables within css to eliminate the use of inline styling in the html files, and was wondering if this is possible?
Here's an example of what I have at the moment

Page front matter:

```
---
section-1-color: #222222
---
```

HTML:

```
<section class="section-1" style="background-color: {% page.section-1-color %}">
```

What I would prefer to do in CSS:

```
.section-1 {
    background-color: {% page.section-color %};
}
```

Is this possible? or is inline styling the most acceptable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styling is the most acceptable method. You define a page variable that is specific for this page, therefore it does not belong in the global stylesheet (IMO). You should do it like this:

Create a .md file like this:

```
---
section-1-color: #222222
layout: default
---

Lorem ipsum
```

Creat a layout file (default.html) like this:

```
<section class="section-1" style="background-color: {% page.section-1-color %};">
{{ content }}
</section>
```

But... to answer your question: It is possible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366018/2397550).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the link you provided works with tags e.g;
{% include user-styles.css %}
but not objects e.g.
{{ page.background-color }}

I'll just stick to inline style for now, but thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Centralize your color datas in _settings.yml

```
section-color:
 1: "yellow"
 2: "#ffffff"
 3: "#f00"
```

In your pages front matter, reference chosen color :

```
---
section-color: 1
---
```

In your layout :

```
<section class="section-{{ page.section-color }}>
```

At the bottom of your main scss file (look for assets/main.scss), that already have a front matter, and then is processed by jekyll :

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
// a lot of scss here
// ...

{% for section in site.section-color %}
.section-{{ section[0] }} { background: {{ section[1] }}; } // toto
{% endfor %}
```